# ¿Cuál es la lógica de la clasificación de oraciones?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

En las lecciones de gramática en español, incluso en aquellas de nivel universitario, es necesario aprenderse diversas maneras de clasificar oraciones, por ejemplo:

1. Oración principal, y oración subordinada, y estas a su vez pueden ser sustantivas, adverbiales o adjetivas.
2. Oración desiderativa, oración dubitativa, oración negativa...

Y así hay varias clasificaciones diversas, pero no he logrado entender la lógica detrás de estas clasificaciones, que parecen ser a veces semánticas y a veces sintácticas, y tampoco logro unirlas todas en un solo esquema.

¿Conocéis algún esquema que incluya todas las clasificaciones? ¿O sabéis exactamente cuál es la lógica de estas clasificaciones? Me parece que si se comprende la lógica detrás de la clasificación entonces se puede fácilmente aprenderla ya que solo habría que deducirla, en lugar de memorizarla.

Answer (score 2):

> Oración principal, y oración subordinada, y estás a su vez pueden ser sustantivas, adverbiales o adjetivas.
>
> Oración desiderativa, oración dubitativa, oración negativa...

Las dos clasificaciones son válidas y compatibles, sólo que la primera es sintáctica y la segunda es semántica.

Las oraciones pueden ser simples, compuestas (por dos o más proposiciones coordinadas), complejas (con una o más proposiciones subordinadas), o compuestas complejas (una combinación de los dos tipos anteriores).

Independientemente de la clasificación anterior, las oraciones pueden ser, según su función expresiva, enunciativas, dubitativas, desiderativas, imperativas, etc.

Veamos algunos ejemplos:

- Quizá llueva cuando llegue.

La oración anterior es dubitativa, por cuanto la lluvia es sólo una posibilidad, y compleja porque contiene una subordinada adverbial de tiempo.

- Quien gane podrá retirar el premio y quien pierda deberá conformarse.

La oración anterior es enunciativa (afirmativa) y compuesta compleja, por cuanto contiene dos proposiciones coordinadas que a su vez contienen subordinadas nominales.

- Come la porción que te ha tocado.

La oración anterior es imperativa y compleja por la presencia de una subordinada adjetiva.